# How do I give a Functor instance to a datatype built for general recursion schemes?

Tags: haskell, recursion, typeclass, catamorphism, recursion-schemes

I have a recursive datatype which has a Functor instance:

```
data Expr1 a
  = Val1 a
  | Add1 (Expr1 a) (Expr1 a)
  deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)
```

Now, I'm interested in modifying this datatype to support general recursion schemes, as they are described in [this tutorial](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/bartosz/understanding-algebras) and [this Hackage package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-fix). I managed to get the catamorphism to work:

```
newtype Fix f = Fix {unFix :: f (Fix f)}

data ExprF a r
  = Val a
  | Add r r
  deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)

type Expr2 a = Fix (ExprF a)

cata :: Functor f => (f a -> a) -> Fix f -> a
cata f = f . fmap (cata f) . unFix

eval :: Expr2 Int -> Int
eval = cata $ \case
  Val n -> n
  Add x y -> x + y

main :: IO ()
main =
  print $ eval
    (Fix (Add (Fix (Val 1)) (Fix (Val 2))))
```

But now I can't figure out how to give `Expr2` the same functor instance that the original `Expr` had. It seems there is a kind mismatch when trying to define the functor instance:

```
instance Functor (Fix (ExprF a)) where
    fmap = undefined
```

```
Kind mis-match
    The first argument of `Functor' should have kind `* -> *',
    but `Fix (ExprF a)' has kind `*'
    In the instance declaration for `Functor (Fix (ExprF a))'
```

**How do I write a Functor instance for `Expr2`?**

I thought about wrapping Expr2 in a newtype with `newtype Expr2 a = Expr2 (Fix (ExprF a))` but then this newtype needs to be unwrapped to be passed to `cata`, which I don't like very much. I also don't know if it would be possible to automatically derive the `Expr2` functor instance like I did with `Expr1`.

Comment: I don't think it can be done like that, not with a type alias like you're trying to do.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Assuming I do end up using a newtype for `Expr2`, is there a way to have the functor instance be derived automatically like I did with `Expr1`?

Comment: You can't have the functor instance derived automatically for something like `newtype Expr a = Expr (Fix (ExprF a))` because `Fix` is not a functor. If you change it to `data Fix f a = Fix (f (Fix f a))` then you *can* write a functor instance that looks like `instance Functor f => Functor (Fix f)` and you don't need a newtype.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wonder if you might be better off using the `Free` type:

```
data Free f a
  = Pure a
  | Wrap (f (Free f a))
deriving Functor

data ExprF r
  = Add r r
deriving Functor
```

This has the added benefit that there are quite a few libraries that work on free monads already, so maybe they'll save you some work.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, IMHO. Just like container types, trees are Yet Another Monad Analogy, with `return` as "construct a singleton tree from an arbitrary value` and `>>=` as "replace leaf nodes with a subtree generated by applying a function to their contents."

Comment: Accepting this question because it gives the most stuff "for free" in this particular case where the `a` parameter only shows up on the leaves and doesn't need to use newtype wrappers. I guess the Bifunctor version is more general though.

Answer (score 11):

This is an old sore for me. The crucial point is that your `ExprF` is functorial in *both* its parameters. So if we had

```
class Bifunctor b where
  bimap :: (x1 -> y1) -> (x2 -> y2) -> b x1 x2 -> b y1 y2
```

then you could define (or imagine a machine defining for you)

```
instance Bifunctor ExprF where
  bimap k1 k2 (Val a)    = Val (k1 a)
  bimap k1 k2 (Add x y)  = Add (k2 x) (k2 y)
```

and now you can have

```
newtype Fix2 b a = MkFix2 (b a (Fix2 b a))
```

accompanied by

```
map1cata2 :: Bifunctor b => (a -> a') -> (b a' t -> t) -> Fix2 b a -> t
map1cata2 e f (MkFix2 bar) = f (bimap e (map1cata2 e f) bar)
```

which in turn gives you that when you take a fixpoint in one of the parameters, what's left is still functorial in the other

```
instance Bifunctor b => Functor (Fix2 b) where
  fmap k = map1cata2 k MkFix2
```

and you sort of get what you wanted. But your `Bifunctor` instance isn't going to be built by magic. And it's a bit annoying that you need a different fixpoint operator and a whole new kind of functor. The trouble is that you now have *two* sorts of substructure: "values" and "subexpressions".

**And here's the turn.** There is a notion of functor which is *closed* under fixpoints. Turn on the kitchen sink (especially `DataKinds`) and

```
type s :-> t = forall x. s x -> t x

class FunctorIx (f :: (i -> *) -> (o -> *)) where
  mapIx :: (s :-> t) -> f s :-> f t
```

Note that "elements" come in a kind indexed over `i` and "structures" in a kind indexed over some other `o`. We take `i`-preserving functions on elements to `o` preserving functions on structures. Crucially, `i` and `o` can be different.

The magic words are "1, 2, 4, 8, time to exponentiate!". A type of kind `*` can easily be turned into a trivially indexed GADT of kind `() -> *`. And two types can be rolled together to make a GADT of kind `Either () () -> *`. That means we can roll both sorts of substructure together. In general, we have a kind of type level `either`.

```
data Case :: (a -> *) -> (b -> *) -> Either a b -> * where
  CL :: f a -> Case f g (Left a)
  CR :: g b -> Case f g (Right b)
```

equipped with its notion of "map"

```
mapCase :: (f :-> f') -> (g :-> g') -> Case f g :-> Case f' g'
mapCase ff gg (CL fx) = CL (ff fx)
mapCase ff gg (CR gx) = CR (gg gx)
```

So we can refunctor our bifactors as `Either`-indexed `FunctorIx` instances.

And now we can take the fixpoint of any node structure `f` which has places for either elements `p` or subnodes. It's just the same deal we had above.

```
newtype FixIx (f :: (Either i o -> *) -> (o -> *))
              (p :: i -> *)
              (b :: o)
  = MkFixIx (f (Case p (FixIx f p)) b)

mapCata :: forall f p q t. FunctorIx f =>
  (p :-> q) -> (f (Case q t) :-> t) -> FixIx f p :-> t
mapCata e f (MkFixIx node) = f (mapIx (mapCase e (mapCata e f)) node)
```

But now, we get the fact that `FunctorIx` is closed under `FixIx`.

```
instance FunctorIx f => FunctorIx (FixIx f) where
  mapIx f = mapCata f MkFixIx
```

Functors on indexed sets (with the extra freedom to vary the index) can be very precise and very powerful. They enjoy many more convenient closure properties than `Functor`s do. I don't suppose they'll catch on.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing wrong with pigworker's answer, but maybe you can use a simpler one as a stepping-stone:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Prelude hiding (map)

newtype Fix f = Fix { unFix :: f (Fix f) }

-- This is the catamorphism function you hopefully know and love
-- already.  Generalizes 'foldr'.
cata :: Functor f => (f r -> r) -> Fix f -> r
cata phi = phi . fmap (cata phi) . unFix

-- The 'Bifunctor' class.  You can find this in Hackage, so if you
-- want to use this just use it from there.
--
-- Minimal definition: either 'bimap' or both 'first' and 'second'.
class Bifunctor f where
    bimap :: (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> f a b -> f c d
    bimap f g = first f . second g

    first :: (a -> c) -> f a b -> f c b
    first f = bimap f id

    second :: (b -> d) -> f a b -> f a d
    second g = bimap id g

-- The generic map function.  I wrote this out with
-- ScopedTypeVariables to make it easier to read...
map :: forall f a b. (Functor (f a), Bifunctor f) => 
       (a -> b) -> Fix (f a) -> Fix (f b)
map f = cata phi 
    where phi :: f a (Fix (f b)) -> Fix (f b)
          phi = Fix . first f
```

Now your expression language works like this:

```
-- This is the base (bi)functor for your expression type.
data ExprF a r = Val a 
               | Add r r
               deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)

instance Bifunctor ExprF where
    bimap f g (Val a) = Val (f a)
    bimap f g (Add l r) = Add (g l) (g r)

newtype Expr a = Expr (Fix (ExprF a))

instance Functor Expr where
    fmap f (Expr exprF) = Expr (map f exprF)
```

**EDIT:** Here's a link to the [`bifunctors` package in Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors).

Comment: Interesting. This is very similar to the solution I had already stumbled upon, except that my implementation of `map` was much uglier because I didn't know about BiFunctors :)

Answer (score 0):

The keyword type is used only as a synonymous of an existing type, maybe this is what you are looking for

```
newtype Expr2 a r = In { out :: (ExprF a r)} deriving Functor
```